# How i Concatenate string to Kendo Ui Gridview column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I bound Amount column in Kendo UI Gridview column

> columns.Bound(c => c.Amount).Title("Amount").Width(50);

I want to Concatenate string "$" to that

So it should look like $5000, how I do this?

Comment: You can use column templates, see: https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/html-helpers/data-management/grid/templates/column-templates

Comment: Try `columns.Bound(c => c.Amount).Format("{0:c}").Title("Amount").Width(50);`

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the currency format **format: "{0:c}"** [Documentation](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing)

```
{ field: "Amount", title: "Amount", format: "{0:c}", width: 50 },
```